# Preventing div Highlighting in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following to show a video an embed video using the video tag and has a flash fallback. In Chrome when I click to play the video it outlines the video in an orange box.

```
<div id="slide0" style="display:block; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; user-select: none; width: 960px; height: 456px;">
    <video id="video0" poster="poster.jpg" controls="controls" preload="auto" width="960" height="453">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="video.mp4" /><source type="video/webm" src="video.webm" />
    <object width="960" height="453" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="resources/videos/flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="resources/videos/flashmediaelement.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=video.mp4" />
    </object>
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the css property `outline` to `none` in your div (or video, i don't know which element is outlined) style attribute, or your stylesheet.

```
#slide0,#video0
{
   outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Still outline when I click on the video. I'm pretty sure it's the video element, because I have other divs named slide1, slide2, etc... that do not highlight.

Comment: Here, when i put the `outline: none` in the video element, the highlight seems to disappear. http://jsfiddle.net/5H7Tj/

Comment: @ENev just to contribute, I have found out that some elements don't necessarily inherit outline:none from the parent. Keep that in mind.